# Number of ways to have lights of equal distances on a street

Tags: elementary-number-theory, word-problem

> The city wants to have street lights along a street that is $64$ yards long. If the street lights are going to be apart at equal distances that are whole numbers of yards, how may different ways can the city do it?

Can someone please shed some *lights* on this question (no pun intended)? I divided 64 yards by $1$ to $64$ and the whole numbers from the division are $1$ yard, $2$ yards, $4$ yards, $8$ yards, $16$ yards, $32$ yards and $64$ yards. Is there a much quicker way to do this for any number $n$ of yards, i.e. a formula perhaps?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The question just wants you to find the number of divisors of 64. perhaps a smarter a way was to recognize that 64 is a power of 2, $(2^6)$, and then find different combinations of it by combinatorics eg;  $$2^6 = 2^3 × 2^3$$

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking how many  factors does $64$ have

$$64=2^6$$

Hence the factors are $2^0, 2^1, \ldots, 2^6$. There are $7$ factors.

In general I will consider the prime factorization of the number $n$.

$$n = \prod_{i=1}^q p_i^{m_i}$$

and the number of factors would be $\prod_{i=1}^q (m_i + 1)$